Is this a standard use of 意識?
From Durarara!! episode 16, many people become like zombies after being stabbed by a powerful entity manifested as a sword, one of the "zombies" tells a main character that it was hard for their conscious to transition to their new state:

最初は私たちの意識が言葉を覚えたりするのが大変だったけど
もう母さんと同じくらいはっきりした意識があるわ

I am used to 意識 being marked with が, but not in the case of having it be the subject performing a transitive verb.
I get the meaning (it was tough for our consciousness to learn words), but is it normal to use 意識 like this?
I mean, could I then say things like:

最近、私の意識が大事なことを忘れている
意識がおのずと気づいていなかったことを気づくようになるでしょう

I guess I feel this usage is a bit strange is all, so I wonder if those sentences are natural.

It is 最初は私たちの意識が(薄れて), isn't it?

Re-checked the srt and there was no 薄れて and not even a pause in the audio

Then don't put an odd dash after 意識が. It indicates there's a pause.

Sorry. I had just copied the srt as is.

"私たちの意識が言葉を覚える" doesn't sound natural when interpreted without context. 意識 by itself does not usually learn or forget something.
However, this sentence makes sense in this context because the speaker seems to be Saika, a creature who can copy and spread her 意識 through a "voice". It is not surprising that such a creature has a different understanding of "consciousness" compared to ordinary humans.

罪歌
罪歌は愛した相手との間に愛の証として『子』をもうける力を持ち、斬りつけた傷から恐怖と痛みを媒体に「種」を送り込み、少しずつ宿主の精神を侵しながら、新たな『刃物』を媒体に妖刀としての自我を発現させる。そうして妖刀の自我に意識を支配された者を『罪歌の子』と呼ぶ。『子』も大元の罪歌同様、斬りつけた人間を『子』にすることができる。

